# jumplist not showing up on the pinned icon (c++/cli - windows 7)

Tags: windows, c++-cli, jump-list

When i pin my app to the taskbar, I don't see the jumplist when the app is to running.

Jumplist: recently opened files that show up when you right click on a taskbar icon in windows 7.

When I run the app, a new taskbar icon opens, instead of the same icon. The jumplist shows up on the running icon, but not on the pinned icon.

Here are the things I have done..

1. SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID
2. added the registry items for the file type.

Jumplist works fine when the app is running. Except that jumplist does not show up on the pinned icon.

My questions are:

1. how do I show the jumplist when the app is not running? or why is it not working? Is it a different registry entry?
2. Why is windows creating a new taskbar icon, instead of opening on the same pinned icon. (I don't change the AppUserModelID)?

Comment: Please clarify your definition of *jumplist*.

Comment: recently opened files that show up when you right click on a taskbar icon.